# How can I remove line containing multiple spaces after equals (=)sign?

Tags: java, string, substring

My file contains the following lines:

**z1D_PreviousAssignedCompany (303760000) = GOIS**

**Previous_HPD_CI_ReconID (303524300) =**

**Previous_ServiceCI_ReconID (303524200) =**

**z1D_TotalOpenIncidentsCount (303070300) = 0**

**z1D_Assignee_Site (303903600) = Bangalore - IND08**

**z1D_Assignee_Phone (303903500) = N/A**

**z1D_Assignee_Email (303903400) = taranveer.vij@in.com**

I am looking for the lines that contain some data after the equals sign, ignoring the ones that do not have any value after the equal sign, like:

**GOIS**

**0**

**Bangalore - IND08**

**N/A**

**taranveer.vij@in.com**

This is what I have tried:

```
if (strword.contains("="))
{

   int num1=strword.indexOf("=");

   int num2=strword.lastIndexOf("");

   String strNew=strword.substring(num1,num2);

   String removeSpaces=strNew.replace("\\s+","");

   System.out.println(removeSpaces);
}
```

Please revert me in case you did not understand my question.
Please do not get upset and down vote, I may lose chance to ask question again in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not using regex?

```
"(?<==)\\s*(\\S.*)"
```

would give you those non-empty strings in `group(1)`.

or you can do with `replaceAll`:

```
String part=line.replaceAll(".*=\\s*","");
```

here check `part` ,it would be either `empty` or the value you need.

#### NOTE, you should fix the mistake in your code:

I just saw that, in your code:

```
String removeSpaces=strNew.replace("\\s+","");
```

string.replace(target, repl) won't think `target` as regex!! it do **literal** replacement. You should fix it if you used this method in the same way in your project.

#### Update, in case you just need to check if a line needs to be removed:

then just check the line with this regex:

```
"=.*\\S.*$"
```

this won't extract values for you, but it will tell you if there is `=` sign in line and if there value (non-empty strings) after the `=`.

Comment: @Kent.. how can i use this regex?? as matcher method??

Comment: @user3711467 do a google, how to extract string with regex. you'll know how to do...

Comment: @Kent.. thats nice but after removing those lines, its creating empty new lines.. i tried with trim() function but still, those empty lines are present between lines..

Comment: @user3711467 do you want to get those values or reformat the file? I thought you want those values. you can check the `part`, if it is empty, skip, take next line, otherwise, `part` has your value, do your businesslogic with it.

Comment: @Kent..i do not have enough reputation to up vote your answer..since i joined recently

Comment: @user3711467 add another regex just for checking. if line match that regex, you should keep.

Answer (score 1):

You are already getting data after "=" sign right

so just add

if (!strword.trim().equals(""))

before sop and you have what you are looking for

hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

Use [String trim()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_trim.htm/) on your line and then you can check if the `=` sign is the last character on your trimmed line, if it is remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of splitting the String is to use the String split method.

```
public String getValue(String line) {
    String[] values = line.split(" =");
    if (values.length == 1) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return values[1].trim();
    }
}
```

If the getValue method returns an empty String (""), ignore the line.